# Why does WP_DEBUG only work after wp_debug_mode() is called?

Tags: debug, wp-debug

With debugging set to on,

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

my instance of WordPress doesn't show any debugging info.

After a lot of searching I figured that after I call `wp_debug_mode()` debug info shows correctly.

Can anyone tell me why calling `wp_debug_mode()` is necessary, since the debugging [documentation page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) doesn't even mention this function?

Is there something in my environment that is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look [at its source](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_debug_mode/):

```
function wp_debug_mode() {
    if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
        error_reporting( E_ALL );

        if ( WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
            ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
        elseif ( null !== WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
            ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

        if ( WP_DEBUG_LOG ) {
            ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
            ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
        }
    } else {
        error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
    }
    if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) )
        ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
}
```

You don't call that function yourself. It gets called by core in [`~/wp-settings.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5f0981788d7adbd25b71addbc415f700eb1c71b5/wp-settings.php#L61) during runtime long before hooks like `muplugins_loaded`, `plugins_loaded` or `after_setup_theme` are available for you.

The only you'll have to make sure is to add

```
defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) or defined( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE );
```

to you `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, @kaiser. I see exactly what it does now. My question is why do I have to call it. Do you have to call this function for your WP debugger to work? Is there a setting somewhere I don't know about?

Comment: @NeluMalancea See update.

Comment: Yes, `wp-settings.php` calls it, yet if I don't call it too, my debugger doesn't work (see my 2nd commend on @Otto's answer).

Comment: @NeluMalancea Turn off all other plugins, switch to the default theme. See if it still happens.

Comment: Found it - "Simple Share Buttons" plugin. Thank you, @kaiser. I should've started troubleshooting with the plugins. It's **interesting** though that the word `debug` is nowhere in this plugin. I wonder what line is causing this. Can you please mention deactivating plugins in your answer, to match as the solution?

Comment: @NeluMalancea I upvoted you comment for visibility and closed the question as _too localized_. No offense, just to keep the more relevant questions and answers higher ranked in the search results.

Comment: Fair. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to call wp_debug_mode() yourself, it's called very early in the process of wp-settings.php.

Perhaps you are defining the WP_DEBUG constant too late? It should be defined in the wp-config.php file, not anywhere else.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a setting, that's what I'm trying to figure out. `WP_DEBUG` is in `wp-config.php`, correct.

Comment: I see it on line 61 of `wp-settings.php`. I'm calling `wp_debug_mode()` in `functions.php` through the `init` hook. If I don't, it doesn't work. There must be something between line 61 of `wp-settings.php` and beginning of `functions.php` that is unsetting the debug mode.